# How is my question about engineering?

Tags: discussion

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74425/power-loss-from-chain-and-sprocket-combinations-of-equal-ratios

I'm simply asking what the difference of power would be to make an atv with a 13t sprocket accelerate the same as one with a 11t sprocket.

What am I asking to be engineered?

If you can't or don't want to answer the question, that's fine.  But don't say its about engineering for a means to delete it.

Comment: Have you read [our policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site/4536#4536) on engineering questions? (We define what we mean by "engineering" there) Especially the "applies our understanding of nature to **specific**, real-world problems". The major issue here is that the question is too specific (which makes it not too useful to other visitors) and isn't directly asking about a physics concept per se.

Comment: @Manishearth So if change the 13t and 11t to x teeth and y teeth, then you'll be happy?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is you are not asking *how* or *why* something works, but rather for the final answer. The only question you ask is "Would you agree its easier to accelerate the chain on the smaller sprocket than the larger?" which is not a physics question. The rest of your post is either background information or a "check my calculation" section.

If you would like your question re-opened, I would suggest that you find ways to pose it in a way that is looking for an understanding of what the physical differences might be between the two systems. Even removing the bulk of the information might help, the question can be as simple as "Why does power decrease as cogs become smaller at a constant gear ratio?"

The numbers don't matter from the physics standpoint, nor does the application. But if you can phrase it as a "Why does this work the way it does" question, it **might** be on topic and would (hopefully) give you the understanding of the problem to solve for the numbers yourself.

Just my two cents.

Comment: The problem is, I already know the why, I just don't know how to arrive at the solution because I don't know if I know everything. I'm not sure what question to ask because I don't know what I don't know.  All I know to do is present the problem and some good soul may say "yes but you forgot to include ____".

Comment: @tpg2114 Well stated, although I would suggest one correction: 'if you can phrase it as a "Why does this work the way it does" question, it **might** be on topic'. Questions are judged on a case-by-case basis so we can't say with 100% certainty if a particular revision will make a question on topic without seeing it happen.

Comment: @Randy That's fair, and I'm sure there are places on the internet where posing a problem in that way would be perfectly appropriate. I don't know of any specific ones, but you could try looking for an engineering forum. This is not the site for that kind of question, though.

Comment: What if I said its a homework problem, would that make it ok?

Comment: @Randy Maybe I'm confused by your comment, but if you know the "why" with certainty, then you should know if you included it all or not. I think you know the trend but not all the processes that cause the trend. Unless I misunderstood the material you presented. So asking for the "why" should solicit answers that explain all the physical processes that matter.

Comment: @DavidZ  This is exceedingly frustrating.  I see questions asking for specific answers and then see lots of answers in great detail.

Comment: @DavidZ Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @tpg2114 oh, the bolding was just to indicate the word I changed, I didn't mean you should actually make it bold in your answer. ;-) (well you can if you want to...)

Comment: @tpg2114  So all I need to do is ask "Why does a sprocket with 13t require an engine with more power to accelerate at the same rate as an engine with a sprocket of 11t?"

Comment: @Randy I can't say with certainty, but that would be much closer to being on topic (in my mind, and I did flag the original as off-topic). More general is better, so I would recommend dropping the numbers and just say "smaller." But as DavidZ pointed out, there is no way of knowing if it will be on topic without seeing it. Just don't take offense with it being marked off-topic, it's "on hold" so it can be worked on/improved so it fits with our goals/policies and hopefully gets you the answers you need.

Comment: @Randy that's better, although bear in mind you're addressing a group of people who may not know what sprockets are or what 13t and 11t mean. So you'd have to explain what is going on in different terms. (You can expect that people will know what gears are, FWIW) Also, whether it's a homework question or not makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @DavidZ The bold just makes it a reminder of my own limitations in deciding the fate of the universe... It never hurts to be reminded of that ;)

Comment: @Randy P.S. it will actually help if you can ask the question in a way that avoids using specific numbers of teeth. So even better than what you posted in your last comment would be "Why does a gear with more teeth need more power to accelerate at the same rate?" (If you ask this, make sure that when you say "acceleration" you mean the same thing physicists do, i.e. the rate of change of velocity.)

Comment: @tpg2114 Ok, if I ask it as I suggested, the responses I anticipate will only tell me what I already know... that the inertial and frictional forces due to the chain will be more meaningful to the larger sprocket. Where can I go to have the process of converting these concepts into numbers explained to me? I'm sure the math site will suggest I try the physics board. There is simply no place for me to put my queston, therefore in lieu of a better site, this question shouldn't be off topic here.

Comment: @Randy Unfortunately just because no other option exists doesn't mean that this is the catch-all. If you look at the [Engineering policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site/4536#4536) there are suggestions for other places that it might be on topic. You might actually find help on Robotics or Motor Vehicle (but I don't participate in either so I can't guarantee they can help you). If you get good answers from somebody giving the concepts, you can see if they will help you in chat to work out the numbers.

Comment: How do I address 2 people in comments?  Use a comma?  Or is there no way?

Comment: @Randy No way, only one at a time. But if you are addressing me, all comments ping me since it's on my answer even if my name isn't in it.

Comment: @tpg2114 Its doubtful anyone would help in chat, since they get no points for it.

Comment: @Randy (3 comments up) you can omit the `@` sign. (5 comments up) like tpg2114 said, there is no guarantee that a particular question will be on topic at some Stack Exchange site. The people at [math.SE] may point you here only because they don't know exactly what is on and off topic for us. You can try your luck at [robotics.SE] or [mechanics.SE], but I have a hunch that you will be better served for this particular question at some other site, not within the Stack Exchange network. (1 comment up) we don't do this for points, you know ;-)

Comment: So even if I address David, you still are pinged?

Comment: @DavidZ I agree with your hunch

Comment: @Randy Yes, I am still pinged since it's on my answer. If you posted on your question above, I wouldn't see it without the @ sign. As for people helping in chat, you would be surprised. It's not all about rep around here, I've spent a lot of time working out problems in chat that weren't suitable questions here (because they were engineering). I would help you if I knew the answer.

Comment: @tpg2114 Thanks for the offer just the same.  And thanks for the help with what to do.  I think I might try the generalized question recommended.  If nothing else, the answers will give credence to my claim when I present it on other venues.

Comment: Don't delete all the comments just yet.  Give me a few to formulate my new question.  I'll use these comments as a guide.

Comment: @DavidZ is this ok? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74578/why-does-a-larger-sprocket-need-more-power-to-accelerate-at-the-same-rate

Comment: @Randy yeah, that seems fine to me. By the way, the normal procedure should be to edit the question you posted before, but in this case it's fine as is.

Comment: @Randy I'm not going to flag it as off-topic, I think it's okay. We'll see what others thing but it's much easier to understand now too. I edited in a clarification that everything else is identical between setups as that was in your original question. Feel free to remove it if it's not accurate.

Comment: @DavidZ Oh, I was going to delete the old one once the new one was up.  I figured it would work out the same.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for that edit!

Comment: @DavidZ I can't delete the old question.  Oops

Comment: @Randy I took care of it for you. In the future you can flag for moderator attention in cases like that (although they're rare).

Comment: I need some help. I have a guy posting an answer to my question who can't grasp what I'm asking. How can I phrase it to help him understand?